# getSelection on DIV contentEditable

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, selection

I am trying to achieve project and I must do a WYSIWYG editor in JavaScript. I can't use an existing editor because I need use my plugins (for example a `colorPicker` or `imagePicker`).

For now I have this HTML:

```
<div class="K_editor" id="idExample">
   <div class="K_links">
      <div class="K_editor_link K_editor_linkBold">B</div>
      <div class="K_editor_link K_editor_linkItalic">I</div>
      <div class="K_editor_link K_editor_linkUnderline">U</div>
   </div>
   <iframe width="696" height="212" frameborder="0" src="js/myEditor_iFrame.php">
      <html>
         <head/>
         <body>
            <div id="contentIframe" contenteditable="true">
               This is a test code, with <strong>bold</strong> text and  <em>italic</em> text.
            </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </iframe>
   <input type="submit"/>
</div>
```

On event click on `.K_editor_link`, a function is open with arguments:

- `tagStart` (example `<u>`, or `<span style="color:#AB1;">`)
- `tagEnd` (example `</u>`, or `</span>`)
- `id` (here `idExample`)

I know get a Selection on `Textarea` but `setSelectionRange()`, `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` are only for `textbox` (XUL), `input` (XHTML) or `textarea` (XHTML).

What can I do for do that?

Comment: The fact that you must use your own plugins don't really force you to write a WYISWYG editor by yourself. CKEditor and TinyMCE allow to use your own plugins, in fact they are structured as a group of plugins around a core.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use. I can not take credit for it since I found it here on SO a couple of months ago. Don't remember where. Hope it works out for you.

```
function getSelectionHtml() 
{
    var html = "";

    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") 
        {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) 
            {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;

}
```

Code is from this question: [window.getSelection return html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222814/window-getselection-return-html)