# Get selected text except for un-selectable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selection

I'm trying to get a character offsets for the start and end of a selection within an article. However, I would like some elements to be ignored from this process.

In my application, the server is working with the HTML before the JS injects a few elements dynamically and it's quite important that the number of characters in the text remains consistent between the server and client.

I hoped it would be as simple as [`window.getSelection()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) along with [`user-select: none;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable). Sadly, although the text doesn't look selected it's still included in the selection's range.

I've written a short example below. I've had a shot at writing a `removeFromSelection` as a workaround without much success. Maybe I need to remove ranges that overlap `.unselectable` and manually fill in the gaps with brand new range objects. I'm getting the feeling this should be easier than I'm making it. How should I be doing it?

```js
function findAncestorOffset(container, node, offset)
{
 if (node == container)
  return offset;
 var parent = node.parentNode;
 var syblings = parent.childNodes;
 for (var i = 0, len = syblings.length; i < len; i++)
 {
  if (syblings[i] == node)
   break;
  offset += $(syblings[i]).text().length;
 }
 return findAncestorOffset(container, parent, offset);
}

function removeFromSelection(selector, selection)
{
 $(selector).each(function(i, node){
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(node);
  selection.removeAllRanges(range);
 });
}

var onSelect = function(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  //removeFromSelection('.unselectable', sel);
  var text = sel.toString();
  $('#out').text(text);
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  var i = findAncestorOffset($('.article')[0], range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  $('#from').text(i);
  $('#to').text(i + text.length);
}
$('.article').mouseup(onSelect);
$('.article').focusout(onSelect);
```

```css
.unselectable {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

pre, .article {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select This</h1>
<div class="article">
<p>
  This can be selected.
</p>
<p class="unselectable">
  This can't.
</p>
<p>
  And this can again.
</p>
</div>

<h1>Output</h1>
<div>
  From: <span id="from"></span>, To: <span id="to"></span>
</div>
<pre id="out">
</pre>
```

Comment: You should get the selected HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222814/window-getselection-return-html   Then you could filter it out, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/xpca4fp5/  But this would need more testing as i think this could be buggy

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a full solution, but it's a start. The idea is to iterate over each paragraph element, and if it's `unselectable` then remove it from the selection. I convert the selection to an array of characters and pad it at the start so that the index matches the index within the entire document.

I didn't pay any attention to the final `to` and `from` values, they're probably not right - but more importantly, if you select the entire text you can see that it's off by a few characters on the second unselectable block. I'm out of time to fiddle with it, but maybe someone else can pick up where I left off.

```js
function findAncestorOffset(container, node, offset)
{
 if (node == container)
  return offset;
 var parent = node.parentNode;
 var syblings = parent.childNodes;
 for (var i = 0, len = syblings.length; i < len; i++)
 {
  if (syblings[i] == node)
   break;
  offset += $(syblings[i]).text().length;
 }
 return findAncestorOffset(container, parent, offset);
}

var onSelect = function(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  var textArray = sel.toString().split('');
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  var from = findAncestorOffset($('.article')[0], range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  var to = from + textArray.length;
  textArray = (new Array(from)).concat(textArray);
  
  var i = 0;
  $('.article p').each((_, rawElement) => {
    var element = $(rawElement);
    var sectionStart = i;
    var lengthOfSection = element.text().length;
    if(element.hasClass('unselectable')) {
      textArray.splice(sectionStart, lengthOfSection);
    } else {
      i += lengthOfSection;
    }
  });
  
  var text = textArray.join('');
  
  $('#from').text(from);
  $('#to').text(to);
  $('#out').text(text);
}
$('.article').mouseup(onSelect);
$('.article').focusout(onSelect);
```

```css
.unselectable {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

pre, .article {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select This</h1>
<div class="article">
<p>
  This can be selected.
</p>
<p class="unselectable">
  This can't.
</p>
<p>
  And this can again.
</p>
<p>
  This can be selected.
</p>
<p class="unselectable">
  This can't.
</p>
<p>
  And this can again.
</p>
</div>

<h1>Output</h1>
<div>
  From: <span id="from"></span>, To: <span id="to"></span>
</div>
<pre id="out">
</pre>
```